# AngularJS from a Chrome Extension background script

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

Given that Angular is tied to the views and bootstrapped in the main extension view, I assume the simple answer is "No, not possible", but wanted to confirm as I can't find a definitive answer anywhere.

My use case is that the extension will be polling for updated content from an API, and updating the extension's badge when found; I'd love to be able to re-use my API service from the extension's Angular codebase.

If not possible, any suggested workarounds for sharing code between the Angular extension and the background script?

Comment: I think you need to use the Event system.

Comment: Any examples of using Events in the background script to run Angular code when the popup isn't open?

Comment: You've put a bounty on a question, but as is it's not a very good question. It's somewhat too broad. Can you elaborate more on your problem? Construct a minimal example _of a problem_, so that an answer would implement that minimal example.

Comment: `Given that Angular is tied to the views and bootstrapped in the main extension view` this is not true. angularjs can be tied and boostraped from any element. angularjs will parse html only with in the bootstrapped element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the input @Xan, @harish - based on your feedback did some more investigation and have the solution. In essence, instead of pointing to a background script in the Chrome manifest, I am pointing to a background HTML page, which I then use to bootstrap my Angular app. The relevent code:

manifest.json:

```
...
"background": {
    "page": "/app/background.html"
}
...
```

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp" ng-csp>
    <head>
        <title>Background Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/app/components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/app/scripts/background.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.run(function() {
  console.log('Hello world');
});
```

Comment: Though I'm looking for a solution for chrome app, thanks for this answer. It is really useful.

Comment: ouch.. no luck. I tried it in my current chrome app project but it doesnt worked. There is an error sayong something like this " Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "chrome-extension://pdknlhegnpbgmbejpgjodmigodolofoi/views/background.html"."

Comment: @boi_echos - what does your manifest file look like? Can you post a new question?

Comment: I've already posted a new question yesterday. And also, I already answered my question. It seems that the "page" property in "background" is not supported in chrome packaged app, I guess. By the way here is the link to my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984640/chrome-packaged-app-use-angularjs-in-background-event-page/29001827#29001827